# change soap usernametoken and password of a soap message using xsl for a Siebel service

Tags: xslt, soap, siebel

I am trying to intercept a web service call, to change the the user credentials of the webservice (username token and password) using xsl.

SO call is like client --> Interceptor (change the user credentials) + any other changes --> Call original oracle ERP/Siebel web service.

This is to be be done through xsl... I tried various options but it didn't work...
Badly need help on this... searched lots of sites but can't find correct answer.

A sample of web service request is given below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cus="http://siebel.com/CustomUI" >
    <soapenv:Header>
        <UsernameToken xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">Bill</UsernameToken>
    <PasswordText xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">Gates</PasswordText>            
         <SessionType xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">None</SessionType>
    </soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
      <cus:SiebelService>
         <a>testvalue1</a>
         <b>testvalue2</b>
      </cus:SiebelService>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This should be transformed using xsl to give following output:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cus="http://siebel.com/CustomUI" >
<soapenv:Header>
            <UsernameToken xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">Steve</UsernameToken>
            <PasswordText xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">Balmer</PasswordText>           
             <SessionType xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">None</SessionType>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
      <cus:SiebelService>
         <a>testvalue1</a>
         <b>testvalue2</b>
      </cus:SiebelService>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://siebel.com/webservices">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="x:UsernameToken/text()">Steve</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="x:PasswordText/text()">Ballmer</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:cus="http://siebel.com/CustomUI" >
    <soapenv:Header>
        <UsernameToken
        xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">Bill</UsernameToken>
        <PasswordText
        xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">Gates</PasswordText>
        <SessionType
        xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">None</SessionType>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <cus:SiebelService>
            <a>testvalue1</a>
            <b>testvalue2</b>
        </cus:SiebelService>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:cus="http://siebel.com/CustomUI">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <UsernameToken xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">Steve</UsernameToken>
      <PasswordText xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">Ballmer</PasswordText>
      <SessionType xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">None</SessionType>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cus:SiebelService>
         <a>testvalue1</a>
         <b>testvalue2</b>
      </cus:SiebelService>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Explanation**: Selecting Names wose elements are in a default namespace is a FAQ. Search the xpath and xslt tags for "default namespace".